# Why is this code returning -1?

Tags: java, arrays

I have some code and line 33 is returning -1 because it could not find the value. But why is it not finding it?! I think it might have something to do with char[] but I'm really not too sure here.

It could also be because of line 31 (int temp) but I really don't know.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

public static void main(String args[]) {

HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

System.out.println("Enter your string to cipher: ");

Scanner s =  new Scanner(System.in);
String str = s.nextLine();

char[] letters = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
Integer[] numbers = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25};

if (str instanceof String) {
    System.out.println("Input received: OK.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Error! You cannot input numbers. Exiting program...");
    System.exit(1);
}

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char l = str.charAt(i);

    System.out.println(l);

    int temp = Arrays.asList(letters).indexOf(l);

    System.out.println(temp);


    }


  }

}
```

Comment: You might have an uppercase letter in your input.

Comment: Btw `char` is essentially an `int`, you can do `l > 'a' && l < 'z'` for example.

Comment: Nope, and even if I did I could convert it to lowercase, so not the issue.

Comment: Just fyi, `str` is always going to be a `String`, since that's its declared type.  You can't check to see if it's alphabetic or numeric by checking the type that way.

Comment: Yes, thanks for making me realise that

Comment: You haven't provided the input for which it is giving -1. If your input string contains anything other than 'a-z', it will give -1. Moreover, str will always be an instanceof String, even if it contains numbers.

Comment: Oh my input is just ab and even a doesn't work

Comment: [Questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a detailed description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) *does not work*, *please help me* are not acceptable.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of the variable 'letters' to `Character[]` and it'll work.

Bonus small optimization advice: move this line `int temp = Arrays.asList(letters).indexOf(l)` outside the loop, as it is you are creating a list on every iteration.

Also decide if you want to use generic collections using Arrays or arrays like `char[]` etc.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what char[] doesn't work but Character[] does?

Comment: Character is an object while char is a primitive
so when indexOf is internally testing for equality it's testing if a Character is equal to a char which is always false even tho to you it looks like the same value

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I didn't know it was testing for a Character not a char. Thanks.

Comment: Please try to avoid txtspk here Fminus - this is not a chatroom! If you can make it as readable as possible, it will same some some editing work in the future. Thanks!